# A simple 1-dimensional inequality, maybe Poincaré inequality or Hölder inequality?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities

I'm reading a paper on the classical Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation inequality [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.04281) and there is a inequality used
$$
|v-\overline{v}|\le \left\Vert v' \right\Vert_{r,I} \ell^{1-\frac{1}{r}}, r\ge 1
$$
where $\overline{v}:=\frac{1}{\ell}\int_I v(x)dx$, $I$ is an interval on $R$, $v'$ is the derivative.

It looks quite simple, quite similar to the Hölder inequality, but where does the derivative come from? And I know that using the Poincaré inequality there will be a constant bound $C$, but then where does the term $\ell^{1-1/r}$ come from?

I think it should be a quite simple question but I am just stuck at it. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, $\bar v=v(t)$ for some $t\in I$. So, for all $x\in I$,
$$|v(x)-\bar v|=|v(x)-v(t)|
=\Big|\int_t^x v'\Big|
\le\int_I|v'|\le\|v'\|_r\, \ell^{1-1/r};$$
the latter inequality is an instance of Hölder's inequality.

Comment: Wow, it is quite clear. I have attemped to do like this but I tried like this: $|v-\overline{v}|=|\int_{x_1}^x \frac{dv}{dx}dx+v(x_1)-\overline{v}|\le \int |\frac{dv}{dx}|dx + |v(x_1)-\overline{v}| $, but it has the residue.

Comment: The mean value theorem solves the problem in my mind. Thx!~

Comment: You are welcome!